# Android SQL problem

Tags: android, sql

I have this sql statement

```
SELECT *
  FROM RecipeInstructions
 ORDER BY INSTRUCTION_NUMBER ASC
 WHERE RECIPE_ID_FK=1
```

execute it using rawquery - have exception...
Syntax error near WHERE...
Why?

Answer (score 3):

WHERE needs to come before ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM RecipeInstructions
WHERE RECIPE_ID_FK=1
ORDER BY INSTRUCTION_NUMBER ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but shouldn't the WHERE be before the ORDER BY?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM RecipeInstructions WHERE RECIPE_ID_FK=1 ORDER BY INSTRUCTION_NUMBER ASC
```